# ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name when doing string formatting in python

Tags: python, sql, text, formatting

I'm trying to run the following query.

```
i=['qwerty12345']
%python
  query='''select 
column1,column2
from table
where hit_id='{hit_id}'
and device_id='{'{AB14233Q-2E60}'}'
'''.format(hit_id=i)
result= sqlContext.sql(query)
```

But I'm getting
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
my device_id is '{AB14233Q-2E60}'
What am I missing here?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this helps anyone else: one of my format placeholders accidentally had an incorrectly closed bracket, so check that your brackets are symmetrical.

Incorrect: `{item1} {item2} {item3)`

------------------------------------^

Correct: `{item1} {item2} {item3}`

Answer (score 1):

The `format` method takes every `{` and `}` as an attempt to write a placeholder.

When that is not the case, you have to escape them like this `{{`, `}}`.

So, you would rewrite your code to this:

```py
i=['qwerty12345']
%python
query='''select 
column1,column2
from table
where hit_id='{hit_id}'
and device_id='{{'{{AB14233Q-2E60}}'}}'
'''.format(hit_id=i)
result= sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes in your device_id

```
'''select 
column1,column2
from table
where hit_id='{hit_id}'
and device_id='{\'{AB14233Q-2E60}\'}'
'''
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. My device_id is  '{AB14233Q-2E60}'. do we need two { in the query? @AlexisG

Answer (score 0):

You would need an escape sequence to solve this. Try adding double curly braces like this `{{ }}` :

```
query= '''select 
    column1,column2
    from table
    where hit_id='{hit_id}'
    and device_id='{{'{{AB14233Q-2E60}}'}}'
    '''.format(hit_id=i)
```

This should hopefully do the trick